# create a kind of personal aggregation of all chat, group messages and different pubsub publications in xmpp

Tags: java, javascript, web-services, xmpp, openfire

sorry for maybe a noobish question and my english.. I want to create a personal aggregation of all messages (chat, group) and posts (from pubsub services) with my xmpp client (e.g. new private messages and posts from different pubsubs will be aggregated in one place (read and unread messages). Furthermore is it possible to receive this aggregated stream with posts on different resources (even if some of the messages have been read on one device but on which not all the messages have been read)?

Is that possible with xmpp? Do I have to create a dedicated personal (user) pubsub to which I will forward (publish) all the messages (or a kind of a webservice for this with an access to a table "inbox" to store the messages). So whatever client of mine which goes online first will collect the private messages and posts from different pubsubs and then will forward to the dedicated pubsub (or web service) from which other resources of mine will  get the messages because all the clients are also subscribed to the dedicated pubsub. Is my thinking right? I hope it's not all trash what I'm writing here..

Or is there a XEP for this?

Please, please help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to notify and monitor other clients on different devices and at the same time need which messages are marked as unread in different customers you will need to write quite a lot boilerplate code.

For sure you will need a centralized web service which will receive the post streams (either in parallel with your client/s or first it will receive them and then send to the client/s). Pub/sub is suitable for this application but you will also need to send some additional data to the service from your clients like the time stamp of the last read message (in order to mark all newer as unread).

I think the easiest way would be to use the webservice as a gateway where all streams will be directed initially and where you can also monitor what is delivered and to which client.

Hope it helped

Comment: I already use xmpp (or jabber protocol) for that and I wanted to realize it with the concept of "pubsub" in xmpp terms. It would be much easier if a subscriber could just update the message xml stanza at the pubsub service that he has read the particular message. But I'm not sure if it's possible and I suppose it's not.

Comment: I dont think you can do it only with pubsub on the clients. Pubsub is just for post retrieval not for managing the post status and distributing it among different clients/devices with complicated policies.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that but what if I create a new "mypubsub" service where all my messages will be forwarded to through the online client. Then if a client reads a message it will post the "read" tag and update the message in the db through a webservice.New resources which will go online (my other clients) will retrieve the messages from "mypubsub" and search for the "read" tag and if it is present, mark the message as read visually. Do you think it could be a solution? Or should I just create a new Inbox table (also forwarded msges) with "read" column and retrieve the messages from there.

Comment: The original pubsub service should not be modified since it could be public with other subscribed clients. But what I mean is a new pubsub (a personal inbox) where only my JID is subscribed, but from which all my resources will retrieve messages.